# Impact force of a viscous solid drop

Tags: mechanical-engineering, glass

I have a drop of molten glass (but could be every solid with high plastic behaviour), and my goal is to calculate the max force during impact.
I think I could use the velocity at the impact point to calculate force like the drop will be a damper, but how can I correlate viscosity with dampening of an "ideal" damper?
Thanks

Comment: behavior of the surface may need to be included.

Comment: I've never heard of that glass possess plastic behavior, what is the state it drops, semi-liquid? You shall provide more information on the molten glass including its structural properties.